# How to cancel sharelink from a file on OneDrive by API

Tags: api, share, onedrive

I want to cancel a sharelink by file ID or path but I didn't find that on [official document](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm) and [github](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/tree/master/items). There is [an API](https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-api-docs/#sharing-and-permissions) for create sharelink so it may have one to destroy the link.

Does anyone know that? Please tell me how to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The removal of links is now supported via the `permissions` facet. Take a look at [this documentation](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/items/permission_delete.md) and let us know if you have any issues.